# mySQL count(*) meaning of arrays

Tags: mysql, sql

In a DB I have a table `tca` with a `status` column. This can be `new, process, completed`, etc.
When I query this table with `SELECT status, count(*) FROM tca GROUP BY status` to find out the count of a certain status I get follwing multidimensional array back

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => new
            [0] => new
            [count(*)] => 6
            [1] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => process
            [0] => process
            [count(*)] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => completed
            [0] => completed
            [count(*)] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

Why are there redundant subarrays `[status]` , `[0]` and `[count(*)]` , `[1]`?

Comment: This is not a SQL question, it's how a result set is returned to the client...

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. May be it'll give the array without the redundant columns.

Comment: @dnoeth - you are the chef of SQL - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have selected 'status' and 'count(*)' , these keys are present in your result array.
Also same result is there with numeric index of result array.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solve your query.

```
Use mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbcon,$countQuery); 
//$dbcon = your db connection variable   // $countQuery = your query
```

Answer (score 0):

*Not that mysql extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5+.*

This is the default behavior of `mysql_fetch_array`

> > By using **MYSQL_BOTH** (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using **MYSQL_ASSOC**, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using **MYSQL_NUM**, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

To get only the associative array, for `mysql` *deprecated* extension use either:

```
mysql_fetch_array($queryResult, MYSQL_ASSOC)
mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult);
```

and for `mysqli`

```
mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult);

// This will return all rows returned by query, while the other return only one row
mysqli_fetch_all($queryResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

*`$queryResult` is the return of the `mysql_query()` or `mysqli_query()`

Answer (score -1):

It is because you have three status : new, process, completed.
Your SQL is to count each status contain how many records.

[0] is means first columns. It is equal to ["status"].
[1] is means second columns. It is equal to ["count(*)"].